# Disable the "Internet explorer is not currently your default browser" warning when using IWebBrowser2

Tags: internet-explorer, mfc, iwebbrowser2

I have a MFC application that launches a IWebBrowser2 window. On users computers where Internet Explorer is not their default browser they get the following warning message

```
"Internet explorer is not currently your default browser. 
 Would you like to make it your default browser?"
```

Is there a way to disable this check before I launch a IWebBrowser2 window?

Comment: Does it needs to be IE? You could just perform a ShellExecute so your HTML is automatically displayed/opened in the default browser.

Comment: No, I want the IWebBrowser2 object (browser window) to be embedded within my application. Mainly so I can catch the events (user clicks a link) from with in the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using CHtmlView/CHtmlEditView?  We do and don't get that message if IE isn't the default browser.